# %d format: a number is required not list

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite

I want to print a column values from a table using this query -

```
cursor = self.conn.execute ("select column1 from table_name where column2 =='%d'"%(number))

Value = cursor.fetchall()   

Print value
```

Comment: that's because `number` is a `list`

Comment: yes! i tried many times but don't know how to print those list values. please see my code https://github.com/svnitHIMANSHU/Raman-spectroscopy-database/blob/master/RAMAN.py                                             i am getting error here:  OperationalError: near "NUMBER": syntax error.           see the line 62, 63, 65

Comment: why this question is not useful? i think you didn't get the question.

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned query format is not secure, you can try binding in this way:

```
self.conn.execute('SELECT column1 FROM table_name WHERE column2 = ?', (number,))
```

According the docs ([Sqlite3 Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html)):

```
# Never do this -- insecure!
symbol = 'RHAT'
c.execute("SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol = '%s'" % symbol)

# Do this instead
t = ('RHAT',)
c.execute('SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol=?', t)
```

Comment: i  am trying to print the values of column1 when i have values of column2, see the line 62, 63 65. Now i am getting the error: OperationalError: near "NUMBER": syntax error.                                                                                  https://github.com/svnitHIMANSHU/Raman-spectroscopy-database/blob/master/RAMAN.py

Answer (score 0):

You have declared your database item as `ATOMIC NUMBER` so either change that to `ATOMIC_NUMBER` or change the code to put inverted commas around the two words "ATOMIC NUMBER".
**AND** for the **5th** time now read the StackOverflow Tour guide so that you can behave in a way that doesn't annoy the people that are trying to answer your questions.
https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @ Rolf of sexony i did that, but now error is -InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.